# How to call back to an Abstract class from extension

Tags: java, extends

so I have to create a class that extends an abstract class and lists the type of homework and the pages that are being used. However, I don't totally understand how to call back to the pages read and the type of homework while also creating an using the createAssignment correctly.This is what I have so far, but it doesnt appear to be working. Any help is appreciated.

```
public abstract class Homework
{
    public abstract int pagesRead();
    public abstract String typeHomework();
    public abstract void createAssignment(int p);
}

public class MyMath extends Homework
{
    public abstract void createAssignment(int p, String t)
    {
       p = 5;
       t = "Math";
    }

}
```

Comment: java is case sensitive try making the abstract class name in same case

Comment: You should remove `abstract` from the method signature in MyMath first of all.

Comment: This code does not compile, take a look at the method signature of ``createAssignment``. It also does not override the one in the superclass (2 parameters). Also: all of the methods in the superclass are abstract, so you have to implement all of them in the subclass.

Comment: Reformat your code please :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple buddy:

Firstly, you will need to implement the abstract methods:

```
public class MyMath extends Homework {
    public int pagesRead(){
       return 3; // any number that you want
    }

    public String typeHomework(){
       return "My math homework"; // any text for the homework
    }

    public void createAssignment(int p){
       // do anything with p 
    }
}
```

As I can see, I guess that you are trying to use a method to populte the field values:

```
public class MyMath extends Homework {

   private int p;
   private String homeworkContent;

    public int pagesRead(){
       return p;
    }

    public String typeHomework(){
       return homeworkContent; // any text for the homework
    }

    public void createAssignment(int p, String homeworkContent){
      this.p = p;
      this.homeworkContent = homeworkContent;
   }
}
```

But, keep in mind that you should change the method from Homework to:

```
public abstract void createAssignment(int p, String homeworkContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code reformatted with syntax fixes:

```
public abstract class Homework
{
    public abstract int pagesRead();
    public abstract String typeHomework();
    public abstract void createAssignment(int p, String t);
}

public class MyMath extends Homework
{
    public void createAssignment(int p, String t)
    {
        p = 5;
        t = "Math";
    }
}
```

You will have to implement the two other abstract methods as well.

And it doesn't make sense to assign to the arguments of the method :-) I guess you would like to assign them to variables in the `MyMath` instance.

I haven't tested it. Does it help?

Comment: Yes! I actually just figured it out and posted my own answer that is extremely similar to yours when you posted it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You clearly does not understand the concept of abstract considering your last question and this one.

When you defined `public abstract void createAssignment(int p);` on your `Homework` class, you were saying "any concrete class (read not abstract) extending this class should implement this method", but on the concrete class you again are trying to implement the same method using the `abstract` keyword, just with a different signature, which is wrong.

Either remove the `abstract` keyword and change the signature:

```
  public void createAssignment(int p, String t) {
    p = 5;
    t = "Math";
  }
```

Or implement the abstract method:

```
 @Override
  public void createAssignment(int p) {

  }
```

Keep in mind though that you will have to implement ALL the abstract methods you defined in `Homework`, unless you make `MyMath` abstract as well. This counts implementing `createAssignment(int p)` "again" if you just overload it.

Answer (score 0):

I edited both of the programs by making one of them abstract only did not work so they are both abstract and createAssignment is now void. This works now. Thank you for the formatting  pointers guys.

```
public abstract class Homework
{
public abstract int pagesRead();
public abstract String typeHomework();
public abstract void createAssignment(int p);
```

}

```
 public abstract class MyMath extends Homework
{
 public void createAssignment(int p, String t)
 {
  p = 5;
  t = "Math";
}
```

}

Comment: Signature for `createAssignment` doesn't match.

Comment: It only works because you made ``MyMath`` abstract as well. You don't override any method, not even ``createAssignment``.